# How to setup storage inside failover clustering

Tags: windows-cluster, storage-spaces

Here is the back story of what I am working with.

I have 2 Vmware ESXi clusters, 1 large at one location, 1 small at another.

I am attempting to setup a windows based failover clustering inside that for things like a DHCP server.

I have setup 3 vms, two in the large vm cluster, 1 in the small vm cluster.

How do I setup the storage for the windows failover cluster? I added a drive to each of the 3 vms, but I cannot create those into a storage pool for the cluster, as they are identified to be in 3 separate primordial pools (as shown below). Each primordial pool only containing of course one disk.

[image: New Storage Pool]

Comment: 1. How about some details on the particular VMware product you're using? VMware is a company. When you say you have a VMware cluster we have no idea what you mean. 2. Why not use DHCP failover instead? It's much easier to implement than failover clustering.

Comment: 1. Vmware ESXi 6.0 on a 5 host cluster at one location, and a 3 host cluster at another.